# How do I control how vim indents ruby blocks?

Tags: indentation, filetype-ruby

When I start a ruby block in the middle of a line, the next line is indented deeper than I'd like.  It's indented from the start of the block, not the start of the line.

Example:

```
some_variable_name = begin
                       42
                     end
```

I would like line 2 to be indented one level deeper than 1.  3 should match 1.

[Some more examples in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdFIm.png). Same logic applies to the case statement below.

Comment: i'm so thankful you asked this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file that controls this lives at `/usr/share/vim/vim80/indent/ruby.vim`. Opening the file, I see it has two variables:

```
if !exists('g:ruby_indent_access_modifier_style')
  " Possible values: "normal", "indent", "outdent"
  let g:ruby_indent_access_modifier_style = 'normal'
endif

if !exists('g:ruby_indent_block_style')
  " Possible values: "expression", "do"
  let g:ruby_indent_block_style = 'expression'
endif
```

Unfortunately there is no documentation for this at all; either in `:help ft-ruby-syntax` or in the file. I tried playing with both, to no avail.

However, at the top of the file there is some author information:

```
" Language:             Ruby
" Maintainer:           Nikolai Weibull <now at bitwi.se>
" URL:                  https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby
" Release Coordinator:  Doug Kearns <dougkearns@gmail.com>
```

At that page GitHub, I see a [newer version of `indent/ruby.vim`](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/master/indent/ruby.vim) which has a new option:

```
if !exists('g:ruby_indent_assignment_style')
  " Possible values: "variable", "hanging"
  let g:ruby_indent_assignment_style = 'hanging'
endif
```

Aha! This looks promising! I saved that file to `~/.vim/indent/ruby.vim`, added `let g:ruby_indent_assignment_style = 'variable'` to my vimrc, restarted Vim, and now I get:

```
some_variable_name = begin
  42
end
```

Which seems to be what you want!

---

Note that instead of downloading this one file, you may want to clone the entire project and load it as a package with some package manager or Vim's package feature. Unfortunately Vim's runtime files tend to lag a bit behind upstream.